# "Нерегистрация"

Tags: орфография

*Нерегистрация* — слитно или раздельно?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Грамота ([нерегистрация | gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)) говорит, что слово **нерегистрация** существует. Оно есть и в "Словаре русского языка" Лопатина. "Не регистрация" - это просто существительное с частицей "не". Сравните:

(1) В этой связи нерегистрация (*отсутствие регистрации - М_Г*) партии Мира и Единства и «Народного союза», в первую очередь, подарок эсерам. [Кремлю не выгодны потери среди партий-участников выборов в Госдуму, – мнение экспертов // Новый регион 2, 2007.10.29]

(2) Должна оспариваться не регистрация сама по себе, а договор ипотеки.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду словообразование по аналогии:  счастье - несчастье,  погода - непогода,  уплата - неуплата?

Comment: Да, я думаю слово "нерегистрация" образовано по тому же принципу.

Comment: Объясните, пожалуйста, дилетанту:  что обозначает на "грамоте.ру" звездочка после проверяемого слова? С бестолковой признательностью...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Нашел в предисловии к Большому орфографическому словарю: "Звездочка при словах с приставкой не- означает, что при некоторых условиях в соответствии с действующим правилом (см. стр. 6) возможно раздельное написание, в этом случае уже частицы не, с последующим компонентом." (а на стр.6 - о правописании НЕ)

Answer (score 0):

**Нерегистрация, слитное написание зафиксировано в словарях.**

- [НЕРЕГИСТРАЦИЯ | slovar.cc](https://slovar.cc/rus/orfo-rus/859233.html)
- [нерегистрация | gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F&all=x)

В то же время на практике встречается раздельное написание, например:

[Вопрос 2. Структура стадии возбуждения уголовного дела | studfiles.ru](http://www.studfiles.ru/preview/5661834/page:2/)

Принимаются и регистрируются каждая информация о преступлении (кроме анонимной) вне зависимости от полноты, подследственности или подсудности. Отказ в приеме сообщения о преступлении, **не регистрация** полученного сообщения, будут являться фактами укрытия совершенного преступления, что влечет за собой уголовную ответственность.

Проблемы с написанием подобных существительных часто связаны с отсутствием слова с приставкой НЕ в словарях, однако слово явно имеет утвердительное значение и применяется в роли подлежащего или дополнения **в утвердительных, но не отрицательных конструкциях.**